# Iterating between pastel colors with a constant perceived luminance?

Tags: color, hsb, perception

For my app, I'd like to create a horizontal, hue-only color slider for picking pastel colors:

[image]

At the moment, I do this by simply using the HSB color model and keeping my S and B constant. However, according to [some of the site answers I've been reading](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36997/why-is-pure-blue-darker-than-pure-green) (as well as my own experience), simply modifying the hue will not generate colors that are percieved to be equally bright. Unfortunately, linearly iterating on a formula like `l = .299 r + .587 g + .114 b` by hue is not as simple.

1. Am I correct in understanding the limitations of HSB in regards to percieved luminance?
2. Is there a good way to iterate between pastel colors (linearly from R to V) with a constant perceived luminance?

Comment: Doing some reading right now... there are apparently color spaces that try to model perceptual differences. https://vis4.net/blog/posts/avoid-equidistant-hsv-colors/ has a good rundown. In particular, it looks like `CIE L*a*b*` can be transformed to a simple HSB-like transformation called HCL.

Comment: could you expand your comment and add it as an answer? that could help other people with a similar problem